# post html form outside of salesforce form

Tags: visualforce, form

I tried to send data with this form to retrieve the html answer but it does not work
someone already had a similar issue?

```
<apex:page  standardController="Lead">
<form action="https://cfsmsp.impots.gouv.fr/secavis/" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="numeroFiscal" value="" />
<input type="text" name="referenceAvis" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="verificationFiscale" />
</form> 

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please do not delete the body of a question and replace it with a different question.

Answer (score 2):

That code isn't going to work, but is has nothing to do with Visualforce, but with how HTML forms and the internet work in general.

`https://cfsmsp.impots.gouv.fr/secavis/` is the URL for an HTML form page, not a form processing URL. It has those two fields, but the `action` attribute for the form on that page is, eg, `/secavis/faces/commun/index.jsf;jsessionid=DBCF5C9F50F935A1D9D3F94A8CF26BC4.secavis-02-01`. Even if you pointed the action on your form to the correct URL, it's very unlikely that the form would accept a submission from outside, and it's certainly not going to write the results back to your VF page.

Comment: thanks for your answer is there any other way to retrieve data from this page i tried http request it did not work!!

Comment: this is the request i tried

Comment: @Anirbas http request is the correct way to go about it. You'll need to post a question containing the code you've tried so far, the error(s) you get, etc.

Comment: @sfdcfox i posted the question my request return the html content no data !!!

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm using a trigger that calls a future method to update Lead after it's inserted  
when i import more than 10 records it doesn't work?
have you  already had this problem ?
thanks in advance